# Height one prime avoidance in normal domains

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian normal domain.  Let $X$ be the set of *height one* prime ideals of $R$, and let $\mathfrak p \in X$.  Can one have 
$$
\mathfrak p \subseteq \bigcup_{\mathfrak q \in X \setminus \{\mathfrak p\}} \mathfrak q?
$$
Moreover, if this is impossible in a Noetherian normal domain, can it happen in a Krull domain?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain such that there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of infinite order in the class group. Then $\mathfrak{p}$ is contained in the union of other prime ideals.

Comment: Why must that be so?  Also, what is an example of such an infinite order element?

Comment: pick any nonzero x in P, then (x)=a product of some prime ideals, but (x) can not be a power of P (since P is of infinite order), so there exists a prime Q not P, such that x lies in Q.